# Is there an easy way to quit Assassins' Creed on PC?

Tags: assassins-creed

If I'm in a memory inside the Animus (i.e. playing the game) and I want to quit the game completely, it seems like I have to follow this sequence of operations:-

- Pause the game
- Select 'Exit Memory'
- Wait for the game to load the lab, with me inside the Animus user interface, then select 'Exit Animus'
- While it's doing the animation for leaving the Animus, pause the game again
- Select 'Exit game' and confirm
- Wait for the title screen to load again
- Select a profile from the menu
- Select 'Exit'

Then the program exits completely. It seems implausible that the developers thought this was user-friendly, so is there a more direct way of leaving the program (and getting back to the Windows desktop) from inside a memory?

Comment: I don't know the answer in this specific case, but when I can't figure out how to quit, I tend to just try Alt-F4.  Some of these steps might be causing your game to save though, so be warned you might lose progress.

Comment: ... and if ALT-F4 doesn't work, opening the task manager (CRTL+SHIFT+ESC, or CTRL+ALT+DELETE if the former doesn't work, heck I noticed even WIN+L works faster than some quitting sequences) and killing the process will work. But as @agent86 mentions, this will not call an game save routines (which ALT+F4 in well-programmed games _may_ do)

Comment: I would assume it continually saves like the original Assassin's Creed did on the PS3. I never had any problem with not saving on  my PS3, so doing like @Zommuter suggests with Alt+F4 or CTRL+ALT+DEL would not cause rollback.

Comment: on xbox, whenever I wanted to quit the game suddenly, I just turned the console off. Autosave is on, so you don't have to worry much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a very common complaint when the game first came out on PC and I don't think Ubisoft ever did anything to fix it.

That said, trying what the users suggested in the comments on your question and try Alt-F4. If that fails, it may be faster to kill the process. It should be auto-saving every time you do anything that needs to persist.